# Limit comparison test $\sum_2^\infty \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3 + 1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3 + 1}}$$

How do I pick a $b_n$? I don't understand the strategy to that, my books just have waves that part and picks perfect ones that work out for their easily contruscted examples but for this one I pick something like the denominator and it doesn't work out. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In choosing a $b_n$, I usually reason backwards, and look for something that will get me what I should get. For instance, the bottom term grows like $n^{3/2}$, so we need something that will leave us $\frac{n}{n^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, so that will be to choose $b_n = \frac{\sqrt{n^3+1}}{n^{3/2}}$ (which approaches 1).

**Clarification:** there are different notions of what $b_n$ should be. Here I am choosing $b_n \to c > 0$ so that we can say $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum a_n b_n$ converges.

Another notion of "choosing a $b_n$" might be to choose $b_n$ such that $a_n > b_n$ and $\sum b_n = \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Ignore constants and other lower ordered terms. By doing this, we see that:
$$
\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}} \approx \dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n^3}} = \dfrac{n}{n\sqrt{n}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} 
$$
This suggests that we try comparing with:
$$
b_n=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

Comment: That seems to lead to a case of L = 1 and undetermined if it has a limit according to the table.

Comment: I suspect that you're confusing the limit comparison test with a different convergence test (such as the ratio test). According to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), in order to show that $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ either both converge or both diverge, we just need to show that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{b_n}=c
$$
where $c$ is a finite positive real number.

Comment: Strange, that isn't what my book calls the Limit Comparison test, I have three sets of conditions in mine for L = 0, L = infinity and L > 0

Comment: Well this is the case where $L>0$, which should not be undetermined.